# Unit test Spring Validator that invokes other Spring Validators

Tags: unit-testing, spring-validator

Parent custom validator of parent DTO:

```
@Component
public class ParentDtoValidator implements Validator {

  @Autowired
  private ChildDtoValidator genericValidator;

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return ParentDto.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ParentDto request = (ParentDto) target;
    // validate child DTO 
    validateChild(request, errors);

  }

  private void validateChild(ParentDto request, Errors errors) {
    if (request.getChild() != null) {
      int i = 0;
      for (ChildDto child : request.getChild()) {
        if (child == null) {
          errors.rejectValue("child[" + i + "]", ValidatorErrorCodes.REJECT_NULL);
        } else {
          // sub path must follow property name
          errors.pushNestedPath("child[" + i + "]");
          ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(childValidator, child, errors);
          errors.popNestedPath();
        }
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      errors.rejectValue("child", ValidatorErrorCodes.REJECT_NULL);
    }
  }
}
```

Child custom validator of child DTO

```
@Component
public class ChildDtoValidator implements Validator {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return ChildDto.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ChildDto request = (ChildDto) target;
    // validate rules
    ...

  }
}
```

ParentDto - ChildDto relation

```
@Data
public class ParentDto{
    private ChildDto[] child;
}
```

Qn: How to unit test ParentDtoValidator without actually invoking ChildDtoValidator?

Since  ChildDtoValidator is Autowired in ParentDtoValidator, how to inject  ChildDtoValidator bean into ParentDtoValidator and be mocked in the line ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(childValidator, child, errors);

Answer (score 0):

Test Class

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
// more imports

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ParentDtoValidatorTest {

  @Mock
  private ChildDtoValidator genericValidator;

  @InjectMocks
  ParentDtoValidatorTest parentDtoValidator;

  @Test
  void ParentDtoValidatorTest() {

    ParentDto parentDto = new ParentDto();
    parentDto.setChild(
        new ChildDto[]{new ChildDto()});

    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(parentDto,
        "parentDto");

    // mock child validator support method to be invoked by ValidationUtils.invokeValidator()
    when(chilValidator.supports(any())).thenReturn(true);

    parentDtoValidator.validate(parentDto, errors);
    assertFalse(errors.hasErrors());
    assertTrue(parentDtoValidator.supports(parentDto.getClass()));
  }
}
```

Take note of static method `invokeValidator` used from abstract class `ValidationUtils` . It requires mocking of mocked ChildValidator class to support input object, otherwise  `ValidationUtils` will throw exception IllegalArgumentException

```
public abstract class ValidationUtils {
  private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ValidationUtils.class);

  public ValidationUtils() {
  }

  public static void invokeValidator(Validator validator, Object target, Errors errors) {
    invokeValidator(validator, target, errors, (Object[])null);
  }

  public static void invokeValidator(Validator validator, Object target, Errors errors, @Nullable Object... validationHints) {
    Assert.notNull(validator, "Validator must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(target, "Target object must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(errors, "Errors object must not be null");
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("Invoking validator [" + validator + "]");
    }

    if (!validator.supports(target.getClass())) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Validator [" + validator.getClass() + "] does not support [" + target.getClass() + "]");
    } else {
      if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(validationHints) && validator instanceof SmartValidator) {
        ((SmartValidator)validator).validate(target, errors, validationHints);
      } else {
        validator.validate(target, errors);
      }

      if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
          logger.debug("Validator found " + errors.getErrorCount() + " errors");
        } else {
          logger.debug("Validator found no errors");
        }
      }

    }
  }
// more static methods
}
```